# Phpmyadmin Database showing following warning during export time?

Tags: php, joomla, xampp, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

i have a big Problem with PHPMYADMIN. When i will Export a Database i get this Message.

> Warning: a form on this Page has more then 1000 fields. On submission,
>   some of the fields might be ignored do to Php max_input_vars
>   configuration.

Note:

> More than 143 tables are there
>
> Database Version  5.5.5-10.1.22-MariaDB
>
> PHP Version   7.0.18
>
> Joomla! 3.6.4 Stable

Comment: i have changed the max_input_vars but again it is showing same warning

Comment: you need to restart your wamp server or xampp server to apply the changes

Comment: already done it i restarted the xampp server

Comment: Then call phpinfo to check what value the option is currently set to.

Comment: Try to provide more info: Exactly what do you do to export data? How many tables are in the database? What version of phpmyadmin are you using? Add this info to your question (not as a comment) ...

Comment: This is a common problem now in phpMyAdmin after their recent update. phpMyAdmin simply uses more inputs now, and so it needs more input vars. Not sure why the problem isn't solved by increasing max_input_vars (try increasing to a very high number, and make sure that your changes are taking effect).